# Is it possible to make a booking system using delphi/lazarus?

Tags: database, delphi, pascal, binaryfiles, lazarus

I am programming a database(DB) in Lazarus as a project and for increased complexity have NOT downloaded any additional libraries. The software is intended to allow customers to check availability of hiring a villa and them make a booking if the villa is available.

Declaring records and writing them to a file acts as a table for my DB. Reading/Writing/Deleting the records in my files has been achieved successfully and I now move on to the point where I use this data to make bookings.

I have 3 tables:

- `Clients`
- `Villas`
- `Bookings`

Now, my problem comes in with the bookings table. How do I make my application know that a villa has already been booked for the period in which a new booking wants to be made. (basically double booking shouldn't be allowed) So far as mentioned, I can only read/write and delete records in my tables and now move on to the booking stage. Please ask if further info is needed

I'm thinking of using the `Tcalendar` but have no idea how to program with it or even if that is the simple way of doing it. Any tips please?

Comment: Like most programming tasks, this starts with spec.  What does "double booked" mean, as far as your villas are concerned?  This depends on whether they're rented by the hour, the day, the week, etc (the booking unit).  If this is a reputable place, then I'm guessing it's not by the hour.  If your booking unit is a day (i.e. ~24 hours), then you need to decide which calendar date you use to identify that booking unit - probably the date that begins the 24 hours of the booking. Having decided these crucial things, it becomes more obvious what you need to do - each villa needs a data structure...

Comment: Maybe all of that is obvious, but you have not provided much detail, and no information on where you've looked or what you've tried.

Comment: "and for increased complexity have NOT downloaded any additional libraries. " - are you saying you WANT the project to be more complex? PostgreSQL has a range data type that would make it extremely easy to check if the villa is booked:https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CD0QFjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.postgresql.org%2Fimages%2F7%2F73%2FRange-types-pgopen-2012.pdf&ei=DXY4U-ryHPOzsAT78oCwCA&usg=AFQjCNHVjWRXjdzQqSL5zJmnU70UnnsTkw&sig2=gkQ-BBejKCfMTPVq2npCtQ&bvm=bv.63808443,d.cWc

Comment: @alcalde haha yep :P IK its stupid but, hey, I'm not incharge of the educational system in the UK! Its crazy :/

Comment: Question title is bad. Is there any general programming language with IDE that makes it impossible to make a booking system?

Comment: Poster posted same question on the Lazarus/FreePascal forum http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,24077.msg144539.html#msg144539

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to solve two distinct problems:

1. Implement logic (not visible to the user) that determines whether a requested booking is available or whether the villa is booked for some or all of the requested period.
2. Implement some kind of visual display for the user to see when a villa is booked.

TCalendar would only help you with the second part, which is the least interesting (because you don't really *need* a visual interface, you could simply pop up a message that says "Villa Not Available").

To write the logic that will tell you whether a booking is available, you will need to refine your data model (or, if you've done that already, explain it to us in more detail).  Specific questions you need to address are:

1. Do you issue bookings against individual villas ("I want to book the Butterfly House for one week starting July 1") or against an inventory of identical villas ("I want to book one of your two-bedroom villas for one week starting July 1").
2. You need to decide how you're going to store the booking information.  When I've tried a task like this in the past, I've found it easiest to store a record for *each night* of each reservation then, for a request, do a separate query to determine if I can satisfy that individual night.  A request for which I can satisfy all nights is bookable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply :) It would be against individual villas. Also, your answer has really helped me and due to this I feel i'd be easily more able to solve this. Once again, thanks :)